# How to add variable in MySQL select query in Python Flask?

Tags: mysql, json, flask

I've seen many similar questions, but none of the answers worked for me. I've tried to use `%s` and `?` in the query to substitute with my variable afterwards, but this still gives me an error.

Here is the piece of code that I have:

```
sql_child = '''select c.individual_id, c.first_name
                FROM individual p1
                LEFT JOIN individual c ON p1.individual_id = c.parent
                WHERE p1.family_id=1 AND c.individual_id is not null AND p1.individual_id = %s;'''
root_id = 504
cursor.execute(sql_child, root_id)
```

The `%s` gives me a syntax error and disappears if I do `'%s'`. When I've tried to print the statement, it only gave me:

```
    select c.individual_id, c.first_name
                FROM individual p1
                LEFT JOIN individual c ON p1.individual_id = c.parent
                WHERE p1.family_id=1 AND c.individual_id is not null AND p1.individual_id = '%s';
             504
```

which is obviously not correct.

Is there any other way I can insert my variable into the query if `%` and `?` don't work? Or is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
sql_child = '''select c.individual_id, c.first_name
                FROM individual p1
                LEFT JOIN individual c ON p1.individual_id = c.parent
                WHERE p1.family_id=1 AND c.individual_id is not null AND p1.individual_id = %s'''
root_id = 504
cursor.execute(sql_child, [root_id])
```

I don't know what library you are using, but the second parameter of `cursor.execute` is usually a list or a tuple.

Comment: I've tried that but got the following syntax error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s'"

Comment: Ooh, I've figured that out: I've used (root_id,) instead. Still thanks!